# Save uploaded image file on server - Java

Tags: java, file-upload, image-uploading

I'm trying to let users upload an image to the server. It's almost doing what it's supposed to, but the file on the server is broken.

```html
<input id=inputPic name='pic' type='file' accept='image/*'>
<button onclick='uploadPic(\"inputPic\");'>Save</button>
```

javascript for uploading on client-side:

```
    function uploadPic(inputId){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "...uploadImage");
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", document.getElementById(inputId).files[0]);
        xhr.send(data);
    }
```

java for handling upload request on server-side:

```java
    @POST
    @Path("{key}/uploadImage")
    public void upload(@PathParam("key") String key, String data) {
        uploadImage(key, data);
    }

    public void uploadImage(String name, String data){
        try{
            byte[] bytes = data.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("..."+name+".png")));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error while uploading image");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Nothing is throwing an error. The file is created on the server but the file is broken. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

**EDIT:**

I think I'm getting closer to the solution. Seem like I have to change the charset cause it looks like

"�PNG IHDR   �   �   �>a�   bKGD � � �����      pHYs     �� tIME�&-���    IDATx��y��՝�?�Vo��]�wA���B��..."

instead of

"‰PNG IHDR   €   €   Ã>aË   bKGD ÿ ÿ ÿ ½§“      pHYs     šœ   tIMEâ
&-£˜ª    IDATxÚíy˜”Õï?ïVoíÕ]½wA³µ€Bƒ€"j*âƒ7...".

I just don't know which charset I actually need to use.

**Edit:**

OK... it's not/not only the charset.

**Edit:**

Got it to work. I used readAsDataURL on client-side to send to file data encoded and decoded it on server-side!